# .NET Core published app fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish

I have a .NET Core console app with target netcoreapp2.1. It calls into an existing WCF service using the Windows Compatibility Pack.

When I run it through Visual Studio, or if I use `dotnet run` to run it from the command line, it works fine.

However, I want to publish it to a .exe file so that I can run it by double-clicking it.

So, I ran the Publish which appears to succeed, but when I try to run the published .exe file it fails with the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.1.2.1, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This error happens on the machine that I ran the publish on, and also if I try copying the published folder to another machine. I believe that `System.Private.ServiceModel` is some sort of deep dependency of the `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` package, but why is this not working? Surely it should have been copied to the output folder automatically?

Is there additional configuration or setup required to get the publish to pull in dependencies automatically?

If it matters, the reference in the csproj file looks like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've manually added from nuget the missing file by installing the `System.Private.ServiceModel` package.

[Link on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Private.ServiceModel/).

This is a hack though, because from the description of the package you can see that it's meant for .Net internal usage, but I didn't find any other options.

Comment: Yep that works - but it worries me what other assemblies have potentially been missed and might then cause runtime errors in the application. I've raised this with the dotnet team here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/10381

Comment: This does not work. I'm having the same problem with Newtonsoft.Json dependency when running it. Somehow `dotnet publish` does not produce a proper output to run, even when adding the nuget dependency explicitly to the main project and when seeing the dependency dll is actually there. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69408758/2948212

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the related GitHub issues*, people seem to have varying mileage with suggested workarounds.

What worked for me was copying the DLL from the runtime folder, to the bin folder, after build, by adding this to my Azure Function app csproj:

```
<!-- https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2824 -->
<Target Name="FixForDotnetWcfIssueBuild" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)bin" />
</Target>
<Target Name="FixForDotnetWcfIssuePublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(PublishDir)bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)bin" />
</Target>
```

Other workarounds include installing the `System.Private.ServiceModel` package directly, or increasing version of System.ServiceModel to 4.5.3, neither of which worked for me.

*

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2824

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4304

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568#issuecomment-433146109

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2349

Answer (score 0):

Add in vsstudio nuget package 
`Install-Package System.Private.ServiceModel`

Now when you publish dll will be included.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was caused by `PrivateAssets="All"` in one of my packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="ULabs.VBulletinEntity" Version="0.7.17" />
```

Background: `ULabs.VBulletinEntity` itself refers to some shared library, that should be automatically shipped without installing a second package. So I tried [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56018426/3276634), which recommends `PrivateAssets="All"` to integrate the shared library.

This works, but when deploying to Linux, the package was not present after `dotnet restore`. This leads to the FileNotFound exception after starting the application. Since I don't get any error, I tried installing it manually using

```
RUN dotnet add package ULabs.VBulletinEntity --version -s my-baget-repo
```

which gave me at least an error:

```
error: Package 'ULabs.VBulletinEntity' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '/app/MyApp/MyApp.csproj'.
```

The error message doesn't have me any usefull information. Mostly they used another version (e.g. .NET Core 2.0 lib in a 3.0 project). In the other case, it seems some kind of wired bug.

After removing the `PrivateAssets="All"`, the package was present in the publish output and I could start the application again. It seems strange for me, but maybe this same someone time. I wasted a few hours with this problem. Used .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Standard 2.0 for the lib.