# Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json when running app from the dotnet publish output folder

Tags: json.net, nuget, .net-5, dotnet-sdk, dotnet-publish

I am finding a problem with `Newtonsoft.Json` library throwing a

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified
```

when running an app as a Docker container and I'd like to know why this happens and why dependency management does not work smoothly.

**I use .NET 5**.

I have a library `MyLibrary.A` that explicitly uses `Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1` for serializing and deserializing json.

I have a different library `MyLibrary.B` that wraps a `MassTransit.AmazonSQS` library. This MassTransit library also uses Newtonsoft.Json, but probably a different version.
If I don't do anything explicit, it seems the MassTransit dependency shows the `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2`. If at `MyLibrary.B` I explicitly add `Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1`, even though I don't explicitly use it, then MassTransit seems to be happy with using this newest `Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1`

Now, I have a web app `MyApp` that uses `MyLibrary.A` and `MyLibrary.B`. It works fine locally, but I use a CI/CD server to generate a Docker image.

Now I spin up this Docker image as a container locally (as a Docker Compose) and I get the error

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It complains about a version that does not even exist. There is no 13.0.0.0, This library seems to go from 12.0.3 to 13.0.1.

I am now going through all my libraries and making sure they all use `Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1` explicitly. And when I detect that some of them use some third party that relies on `Newtonsoft.Json` I add explicitly the very same version, so that I can get everywhere the `13.0.1` version.

---

**UPDATE 1: My workaround didn't work**. I don't know what else to try.

I have even added the `Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1` explicitly to my webapp so I was hoping that at least at runtime it has it available.

Also, if I run my web up locally as a standard kestrel AspNetCore app (.NET 5) it launches properly. What is going on? Why is my docker container complaining about `Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.0.0` not being found?

These are the traces when attempting to run as a Docker container

```
docker run -p 8080:80 \
>     -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production \
>     registry.gitlab.com/sample/foo-integration-service:latest
Unable to find image 'registry.gitlab.com/sample/foo-integration-service:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from sample/foo-integration-service
07aded7c29c6: Pull complete 
97aff7269a5a: Pull complete 
633b89d569a5: Pull complete 
bd0e639a2ac9: Pull complete 
a9a5571a369e: Pull complete 
9569d825ee3a: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:5499b40392512f1731890ccf1ee13507769b733ee2f30c95d281f0550f7a892e
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/sample/foo-integration-service:latest
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at foo.ItgService.Program.Main(String[] args) in /builds/sample/foo-integration-service/src/foo.ItgService/Program.cs:line 10
```

---

**UPDATE 2**: I decided to match MassTransit dependency `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2` everywhere in my libraries.
**The problem remains.**
The error is now

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't get it. All my dependencies of `Newtonsoft.Json` are now `11.0.2` and still it complains. I'll add this version explicitly (even though I don't directly need it) at the web app main assembly and see if it still complains about it.

---

**UPDATE 3**: Still same problem after adding `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2` to all my libraries and after adding that very same dependency to my web app assembly as a dependency.

As per Chris' comment I have now a `.dockerignore`.

```
bin/
obj/
```

The way I build the image is, with GitLab, with a standard `dotnet build`, `dotnet publish` and then copying all the contents of publish folder into the Docker image like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
COPY publish/ .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyCompany.ItgService.dll"]
```

More specific, I use Kaniko and this is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: 1000
  PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR: publish
  ENTRYPOINT_DLL: ReplaceMe.dll
  CLUSTER_NAME: ReplaceMe
  SERVICE_NAME: ReplaceMe

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - publish
  - delivery

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test
    expire_in: 8 hour
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never  
    - when: always

test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: localstack/localstack:0.12.17.5
      alias: localstack
  variables:
    # Localstack with SNS and SQS
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
    EDGE_PORT: "4566"
    SERVICES: "sns,sqs"
  before_script:
    - rounds=10;
      while [ $rounds -gt 0 ]; do
        curl http://localstack:4566 && echo OK && break || echo FAIL
        rounds=$rounds - 1;
        sleep 5;
      done;
  script: dotnet test --blame --configuration Release
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never  
    - exists:
      - test/**/*Tests.csproj

publish:
  stage: publish
  before_script:
    - export PATH=$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools
    - dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool --version 5.7.0
    - dotnet gitversion
    - SEMVER=$(dotnet gitversion -showvariable semver)
    - mkdir version
    - echo "${SEMVER}" > ./version/semver
    - APP_VERSION=$(cat ./version/semver)
  script:
    - dotnet publish -c Release -o $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR -p:Version=$APP_VERSION
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR/
      - version/
    expire_in: 8 hour
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never  
    - when: always

container_registry:
  stage: delivery
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - IMAGE_TAG=$(cat ./version/semver)
    - echo "bin/" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.dockerignore
    - echo "obj/" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.dockerignore
    - echo "FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - echo "COPY $PUBLISH_OUTPUT_DIR/ ." >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - echo "EXPOSE 80" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - echo "ENTRYPOINT [\"dotnet\", \"$ENTRYPOINT_DLL\"]" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - cat /kaniko/.docker/config.json
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - when: always
```

I don't know if the `dotnet publish` is messing something up for docker or whether there is some flaw in my process (it works fine for all other services). What might be the problem?

I can see `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` among the files produced by `dotnet publish` along with `MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport` and all others that are supposedly being copied properly to the Docker image.

Also, If I open the `.deps.json` I can see all references to `Newtonsoft.Json` are `11.0.2`, so no version conflict anymore (I think!).

I'm out of ideas.

---

**UPDATE 4**
I've just cleared all my local nuget packages (using Ubuntu)

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
Clearing NuGet HTTP cache: /home/diegosasw/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache
Clearing NuGet global packages folder: /home/diegosasw/.nuget/packages/
Clearing NuGet Temp cache: /tmp/NuGetScratch
Clearing NuGet plugins cache: /home/diegosasw/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache
Local resources cleared.
```

An interesting thing is that when I restore dependencies after that on my project

```
dotnet restore
```

I can see at `/home/diegosasw/.nuget/packages/newtonsoft.json`
that there are versions `11.0.2` and `9.0.1`

So I guess somewhere somehow a sub-dependency is using Newtonsoft 9.0.1, even though there is no trace of a `Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1` in my the `*.deps.json` that my `dotnet publish` produces, and I'm wondering whether this is related to my problem, maybe because that's the assembly being loaded and the `11` is being ignored?

---

**UPDATE 5**
I've just seen that the `Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1` is being used by some test project, because I can trace it at `coverlet.collector.deps.json` under `coverlet.core 1.0.0` and the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0`

I guess it's not the cause of my problem then.

Also I've verified with `docker export $(docker ps -lq) -o foo.tar` that the container has the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`.

I would like to understand why is this happening and learn how to better troubleshoot these kind of things.

---

**UPDATE 6 (4 Oct)**

**I don't think the problem is with Docker. I think the problem is likely with `dotnet publish` or something I'm missing or doing wrong.**

I have left Docker outside since I didn't see anything wrong there.
I tried to simply do a

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o publish
```

and execute the app in that
publish folder with `dotnet MyCompany.ItgService.dll` to reproduce the exception.

But before publishing, when I run the application with a

```
dotnet run -c Release --project src/Rubiko.ItgService
```

I don't get that exception.

See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/21716 for full details, traces, tree structure, etc.

**Summary**

The questions are:

- Why `dotnet publish` does not seem to produce everything my app needs to run?
- Why does it complain at runtime about an assembly that is there?

  ```
  $ ls publish/ | grep Newtonsoft
  Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll*
  Newtonsoft.Json.dll*
  ```

---

**FINAL UPDATE**: Problem solved. See my own response where info on how to properly troubleshoot these kind of issues and how I solved it by ensuring my test projects (that use different version of the library) don't publish artifacts and overwrite the desired dependency assembly.

Comment: Bounty initiated. As per Update 6 the problem does not seem with docker because I can reproduce it locally without docker. It seems related to `dotnet publish`, what it generates and/or the way I expect it to work. Question and title updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved the mystery. It had nothing to do with Docker. It kind of had something to do with `dotnet publish` but the SDK works well.

The problem was, as initially suspected, with a version conflict. When publishing with `dotnet publish -c Release -o publish` I could see the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` there. But the following made me suspicious

```
ls publish/ -al | grep Newtonsoft
-rwxrw-r-- 1 diegosasw  89K mar 22  2017 Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll*
-rwxrw-r-- 1 diegosasw 641K mar 24  2018 Newtonsoft.Json.dll*
```

2018 seems a bit old for that version. What if.. that `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly being published wasn't the version `11.0.2` after all?

I updated all my libraries to match MassTransit dependency on `Newtonsoft 11.0.2` but my findings on Update 4 made me think there was some other project depending indirectly on `Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1`, and that's why I could see that nuget package being cached locally.

If, somehow, the assembly being published is not the expected `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2` but the `Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1`, the error would make sense when complaining about not finding the assembly `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2`

Bingo!

I installed `exiftool` in my Ubuntu to check dll and exe versions.

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

I run the following

```
$ exiftool publish/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.88
File Name                       : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Directory                       : publish
File Size                       : 465 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:07:19 19:52:18+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:10:04 12:53:14+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:10:04 12:44:39+02:00
File Permissions                : rwxrw-r--
File Type                       : Win32 DLL
File Type Extension             : dll
MIME Type                       : application/octet-stream
Machine Type                    : Intel 386 or later, and compatibles
Time Stamp                      : 2016:06:13 13:05:00+02:00
Image File Characteristics      : Executable, Large address aware, DLL
PE Type                         : PE32
Linker Version                  : 48.0
Code Size                       : 465920
Initialized Data Size           : 2048
Uninitialized Data Size         : 0
Entry Point                     : 0x738b6
OS Version                      : 4.0
Image Version                   : 0.0
Subsystem Version               : 4.0
Subsystem                       : Windows command line
File Version Number             : 9.0.1.19813
Product Version Number          : 9.0.1.0
File Flags Mask                 : 0x003f
File Flags                      : (none)
File OS                         : Win32
Object File Type                : Dynamic link library
File Subtype                    : 0
Language Code                   : Neutral
Character Set                   : Unicode
Comments                        : Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET
Company Name                    : Newtonsoft
File Description                : Json.NET .NET Standard 1.0
File Version                    : 9.0.1.19813
Internal Name                   : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Legal Copyright                 : Copyright © James Newton-King 2008
Legal Trademarks                : 
Original File Name              : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Product Name                    : Json.NET
Product Version                 : 9.0.1
Assembly Version                : 9.0.0.0
```

and as you can see, the published assembly is `Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1`. A mix of relief invades me.

I went to my test projects and added the following to the `*.csproj`

```
<IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>
```

and

```
rm -rd publish
dotnet publish -c Release -o publish
```

Moment of truth

```
$ exiftool publish/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.88
File Name                       : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Directory                       : publish
File Size                       : 641 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:03:24 18:44:14+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:10:04 12:44:38+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:10:04 12:57:29+02:00
File Permissions                : rwxrw-r--
File Type                       : Win32 DLL
File Type Extension             : dll
MIME Type                       : application/octet-stream
Machine Type                    : Intel 386 or later, and compatibles
Time Stamp                      : 2098:12:14 20:33:48+01:00
Image File Characteristics      : Executable, Large address aware, DLL
PE Type                         : PE32
Linker Version                  : 48.0
Code Size                       : 653824
Initialized Data Size           : 2048
Uninitialized Data Size         : 0
Entry Point                     : 0xa16b6
OS Version                      : 4.0
Image Version                   : 0.0
Subsystem Version               : 4.0
Subsystem                       : Windows command line
File Version Number             : 11.0.2.21924
Product Version Number          : 11.0.2.0
File Flags Mask                 : 0x003f
File Flags                      : (none)
File OS                         : Win32
Object File Type                : Dynamic link library
File Subtype                    : 0
Language Code                   : Neutral
Character Set                   : Unicode
Comments                        : Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET
Company Name                    : Newtonsoft
File Description                : Json.NET .NET Standard 2.0
File Version                    : 11.0.2.21924
Internal Name                   : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Legal Copyright                 : Copyright © James Newton-King 2008
Legal Trademarks                : 
Original File Name              : Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Product Name                    : Json.NET
Product Version                 : 11.0.2
Assembly Version                : 11.0.0.0
```

Now the assembly published is the expected `11.0.2`.

I verify that running my app from the publish folder now works fine!

```
cd publish
dotnet MyCompany.ItgService.dll
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a similar issue, I'm not using MassTransit at all. There does seem to be some sort of issue in the dotnet publish command to let this happen.

Comment: By chance are you using coverlet for code coverage? I'm running into this issue in a WPF application and it appears the root cause is coverlet is copying its dependencies into the publish folder at the very end. They seem to have fixed the issue in the next (unreleased) version, see here https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/1258

Comment: @AlexHelms yes, Coverlet is one of the dependencies my xunit test projects have. In any case I mark my test projects as `IsPublishable` `false` in *csproj to avoid those subdependencies mess with the main project dependencies. Test projects just need to run in my pipeline, not to become part of deployable artifacts. Thanks for the link

Comment: I saw this using `dotnet lambda package` which executes `dotnet publish`. I ended up having to delete the `bin` and 'obj` directories in my lambda project directory in order for dotnet publish to copy the correct Newtonsoft.Json.dll file into the publish directory :/

Comment: @diegosasw thank you for posting it, it saved a lot of my time on investigation with exactly the same root cause (Newtonsoft version in test libraries)

Comment: @AlexHelms - Thank you for mentioning coverlet as a culprit for overwriting ones Newtonsoft dependency. I have been hunting for 2 days and this did the trick.

Comment: Just a comment for posterity: As far, as I know, the DLL file you have analyzed using exiftool will have metadata on that file, (e.g. the version number or assembly version number or even project version number will be of the file), but not necessarily on the NuGet package, the file is from. And although in this case those seem to be fairly in line, in many cases the version numbers of files contained in a NuGet package, have nothing to do with the version number of the package. You should rather get the package and compare its contents to the files you've found.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the version that MassTransit depends upon, which is much earlier than v13. Upgrading past that without the proper assembly redirects is likely causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'm moving everything to `11.0.2` to match MassTransit's version and hopefully I solve the issue like that.

I'm just surprised as in why explicitly loading `13.0.1` in my MassTransit wrapper and even in the app's startup assembly was not enough. I guess the loaded assembly is still `11.0.2` (likely coming from mass transit) and I'd have to go with plan B of binding redirects or something. Updated question to reflect it. Definitely not a MassTransit problem but a typical nuget dependency hell with widely used library :)

Comment: It didn't work.. Update 2

Comment: You're dealing with something else, do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes all the noise in the .NET build for Docker?

Comment: I don't use any dockerignore afaik. I've added UPDATE 3 with the way I generate the image, which is basically copying the result of a `dotnet publish` into the docker image with kaniko. I can see Newtonsoft.Json.dll among the files produced by `dotnet publish` along with `MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport` and all others

Comment: Well, you need one, otherwise you get things copied that shouldn't be copied to the docker image. See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/).

Comment: I've added the .dockerignore but it does not make any difference. As I understand it, this is just to avoid copying unnecessary things. Will keep investigating, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with the Newtonsoft package in my .NET core 3.1 web application (not using docker). Neither in my main project (web app) nor in the class library (implemented for sending emails) I explicitly referenced `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`. Running locally on  my machine a `dotnet publish` created the web app correctly with `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` (**v11.0.2**). This is the correct dll, I have checked it in the `*.deps.json`.
Same command on my windows server which I use for the build step in my deplyoment pipeline created a different `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` (**v9.0.1**). With this one my web app did not run correctly (same error like you).

What worked for me: I deleted the folder `C:\Program Files\dotnet` manually. Then I reinstalled the latest .NET SDK x64 on my build server. And **BOOM**, correct `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` (**v11.0.2**) was published. Before that I deinstalled an old Visual Studio 2019 instance and installed a fresh Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise IDE. Apparently, this does not replace the dotnet folder and has no effect. So my conclusion is that the `dotnet.exe` was buggy I had installed on my server and did not restore correctly the nuget package for Newtonsoft.