# Newtonsoft.Json dependency not publishing with the right version on "dotnet publish -o <other folder>"

Tags: c#, dll, build, dependencies, production-environment

### Problem

So basically, i'm in DLL hell.

I have a dotnet 5.0 + react project where a C# dependency (I assume `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`) needs another one `Newtonsoft.Json`.

When building and publishing in release or debug in the bin folder, the project runs perfectly fine and all the dependencies and .dll are loaded correctly. But as soon as I use the option `-o` for `dotnet publish`, the Newtonsoft.Json.dll created in the published folder is of version 9.0.0.0, which throws an error when trying to run the server in production, since it expects it to be of version 12.x.x.x.

### What I've tried

Currently I have a fix, which is to build independently the correct version (12.x.x.x or higher) of the dll file of Newtsoft.Json and put it in the published folder when going in production, but obviously I would like to know of other possible fixes or more direct ones without needing to do extra steps when deploying in production and help people who face the same problem with this dependency or another in the future.

- I have tried including the dependency explicitely with the correct version in the .csproj but the dependency still was outputing at version 9.0.0.0.
- Another fix would be to downgrade the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson to a version that accepts 9.0.0.0 but that opens up a whole other can of worms
- I have tried clearing my nuget packages, that did not work either.
- [I have tried this very recent stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408758/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-when-running-app-from-the-dotnet) where the OP faced a similar issue, but their fix of adding False to their test project didn't work for me, since my test project does not use Newtonsoft.Json.

### Files

- **dependencies listed in the .csproj**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="5.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Bson" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

- **Outputed Newtonsoft.Json.dll**

```
// C:\Users\***\published\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
// Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
// Global type: <Module>
// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: v4.0.30319
// This assembly is signed with a strong name key.
// Hash algorithm: SHA1
// Public key: 0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100f561df277c6c0b497d629032b410cdcf286e537c054724f7ffa0164345f62b3e642029d7a80cc351918955328c4adc8a048823ef90b0cf38ea7db0d729caf2b633c3babe08b0310198c1081995c19029bc675193744eab9d7345b8a67258ec17d112cebdbbb2a281487dceeafb9d83aa930f32103fbe1d2911425bc5744002c7

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(/*Could not decode attribute arguments.*/)]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("9.0.1")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETStandard,Version=v1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Json.NET .NET Standard 1.0")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Newtonsoft.Json.Schema, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100f561df277c6c0b497d629032b410cdcf286e537c054724f7ffa0164345f62b3e642029d7a80cc351918955328c4adc8a048823ef90b0cf38ea7db0d729caf2b633c3babe08b0310198c1081995c19029bc675193744eab9d7345b8a67258ec17d112cebdbbb2a281487dceeafb9d83aa930f32103fbe1d2911425bc5744002c7")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Newtonsoft.Json.Tests, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100f561df277c6c0b497d629032b410cdcf286e537c054724f7ffa0164345f62b3e642029d7a80cc351918955328c4adc8a048823ef90b0cf38ea7db0d729caf2b633c3babe08b0310198c1081995c19029bc675193744eab9d7345b8a67258ec17d112cebdbbb2a281487dceeafb9d83aa930f32103fbe1d2911425bc5744002c7")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Newtonsoft.Json.Dynamic, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100cbd8d53b9d7de30f1f1278f636ec462cf9c254991291e66ebb157a885638a517887633b898ccbcf0d5c5ff7be85a6abe9e765d0ac7cd33c68dac67e7e64530e8222101109f154ab14a941c490ac155cd1d4fcba0fabb49016b4ef28593b015cab5937da31172f03f67d09edda404b88a60023f062ae71d0b2e4438b74cc11dc9")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Newtonsoft")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Json.NET")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © James Newton-King 2008")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("9.0.1.19813")]
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("9.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Wired bug, Checked all MS docs, hard to find the clue

Answer (score 4):

Wish I could give an explanation WHY it happens but I actually don't get it. One clue is to check your `project.assets.json` in the `/obj` folder for which dependency actually requires Newtonsoft in the version 9 (do a full-text search on the exact version number).

Then if you have identified the package(s) - in our case it was `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` - you can upgrade the package so that it uses a newer Newtonsoft version. In our case we explicitely added this package in the upgraded version. Alternatively, setting "PrivateAssets=true" onto the dependency seems to work too.

If there are some packages with version 9 and some with other packages we actually noticed that the behavior not deterministic, so the published DLL will sometimes be version 9 and sometimes version 13.