# Conflict of versions after upgrading to .NET 6 with ServiceCollection

Tags: .net-assembly, .net-6.0

Upgrading from .NET 5 to .NET 6 is proving not so straightforward as I expected.

All my unit test projects fail to compile due to the following error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'ServiceCollection' exists in both 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'    Sample.DynamoDb.FunctionalTests C:\src\my-solution\test\Sample.DynamoDb.FunctionalTests\DependencyInjectionTests\GetServiceTests.cs 22  Active
```

They reference class libraries that depend on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` version 6
but for some reason it seems there is a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` in the test project itself. Probably dragged across by some of the packages I use (and I don't know which one).

This is my test project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>Enable</Nullable>
        <IsPackable>False</IsPackable>
        <IsPublishable>False</IsPublishable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.0.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Sample.DynamoDb.DependencyInjection\Sample.DynamoDb.DependencyInjection.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Anyone with a similar problem or an idea on how to troubleshoot and find the issue or a workaround?

Comment: And `csproj` for `Sample.DynamoDb.DependencyInjection`?

Comment: Solved, see my answer. Thank for your time!

Comment: Should we guess -  you didn't upgrade the packages in `Sample.DynamoDb.DependencyInjection.csproj`? Or the test project?

Comment: I did upgrade all packages, but it turns out some third party dependency had a dependency on microsoft logging 5.0.0.

It's now SOLVED. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not answer the question within the answer post. I've rolled back those edits. Use the answer posts, which it looks like you've now done.

Comment: May I ask what you did to solve the problem?

Comment: @JanHansen see my answer below. Also this may help troubleshooting https://stackoverflow.com/a/69434859/2948212

Answer (score 9):

It turns out the problem was because some referenced project, referenced another, that referenced another... that had a nuget dependency `EventStore.Client.Grpc` that depends, itself, on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 5.0.0`

And that `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` bring the subdependency `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.0`

Having a look at my test project's `obj/project.assets.json` helped me trace that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by explicitly installing the nuget package:

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 8.0.0