# Nuget package dependencies issue

Tags: c#, nuget, teamcity, artifactory

I have a project Customer.Invoices that is a nuget package the csproj file has the following below.  The PackageReference Customer.Prices is a nuget package referenced within the Customer.Invoices project.

The Customer.Groups project reference is just a referenced project within the Customer.Invoices solution.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Customer.Prices" Version="1.0.0.14" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CustomerGroups\CustomerGroups.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I now am using the Customer.Invoices nuget package which is the main package I need in another C# project. I am running into two issues:

1.) if I don't also add the Customer.Prices nuget package it says it can't find the assembly when running a method in the Customer.Invoices project.

2.) I am getting an assembly not found for the CustomerGroups project.

How do I resolve these issues as I know there are include assets etc. but not sure how to handle the dependencies.   For the second issue not sure if this would work is adding privateassets=all to the project reference like so as this is a .Net Core 2.2 project:

```
<ProjectReference PrivateAssets="all" Include="..\CustomerGroups\CustomerGroups.csproj" />
```

Again not sure that is correct as I don't quite understand yet the assets but also need to figure out can I have the Customer.Prices assembly working without also having to add that nuget package.

Thanks for any help

Comment: In the "old" .csproj file format, dependencies were not ... transitive? (I don't know the right word), but in the new format they are. Let me explain. If you have 3 projects, A, B, and C. A references B (but not C), and B references C. When you compile them all, in the old style, the output folder for A would contain A and B, but not C. In the new format, by default C will also be included. Do you know if you have a new style .csproj file, or a new style? Do you have a bunch of entries inside, one for each .cs file?

Comment: Hi @LasseV.Karlsen I modified the question also showing the csproj references.   This is a .Net Core 2.2 class library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both isses are related to how packages are built and resolved. Suppose you have projects `A` and `B` and `A` references `B`. `A` references a package called `A-Package`. `B` references a package called `B-Package`.

### Old Project Format

In an old-style project (prior to SDK-Style Format) the output of a project after building will contain only libraries and contents of direct dependencies. Here, the output folder of `A` will contain files from `A`, `B` and `A-Package`, while the output folder of `B` will contain files from `B` and `B-Package`. This will happen with `packages.config` and `PackageReference` as well.

### SDK Project Format

The [SDK project format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) with `PackageReference` (which is the default for .NET Core) supports *transitive dependencies*. This is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution). This means if `A` references `B` and `B` references a package `B-Package`, then `A` will also get the contents of `B-Package`. As for the example above, the output folder of `A` will contain files from `A`, `B`, `A-Package` and also `B-Package`.

So the issue in question 1 is most probably the result of using the wrong framework, or not using the SDK-Style format with `PackageReference`.

### Project References

The second issue is that project references are not copied to your package. This is why the assemblies are not found. At the moment this is not supported, but there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979310/including-referenced-project-dlls-in-nuget-package-net-core-rc3-csproj-file). `PrivateAssets`, `IncludeAssets` and similar attributes will not help here.

Comment: thanks appreciate it I am going to get much more familiar with this.

Comment: The csproj file just shows <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> so not sure what Sdk would make sure all the dependencies are included transient.

Comment: "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" and variations of it are new SDK-style project types that enable transitive dependencies. All of your projects should use this type.