# Custom Nuget package shows missing dependency error

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependencies, nuget

I have two class libraries in a single solution (.NET Core). One of them (`cl1`) is a main library and it depends on another library (`cl2`). I have added a `.nuspec` file with the required metadata only (no dependencies, no files) for the `cl1` project in the project folder (same location of `.csproj` file) and I have set `GeneratePackageOnBuild` propery to `true`.
Whenever I am building the class library (`cl1`), the `.nupkg` is created automatically in the debug/release folder.

When I check the generated `.nupkg` file, I am see two strange things:

1. The generated `.nuspec` file is different than what I have added in the project folder
2. `cl2` is mentioned as a dependency in the newely generated `.nuspec` file, but the DLL for `cl2` is not included in the `lib` folder of the `.nupkg`. So, whenever I consume this package in another solution, I am getting the error `No packages exist with this id in source(s)` for the `cl2`.

I have surfed in internet, but was not able to find a proper solution for the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I have added a .nuspec file [...] in the project folder(same location of .csproj file)

You have to specify the path to your own NuSpec file in the `.csproj` using the `NuspecFile` tag, otherwise it will be ignored and the package will be created with the metadata from the `.csproj` file instead, see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj). You need to use either a relative or an absolute path to the file, for example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <NuspecFile>cl1.nuspec</NuspecFile>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

> 1. The generated .nuspec file is different than what I have added in the project folder

As already stated, your NuSpec file is probably not included. However, even if it is, there can be differences, because *some information*, e.g. source file locations are unnecessary and the target locations are in most cases given by the internal package file structure itself, so it is not there because it is redundant.

> 2. cl2 is mentioned as a dependency in the newely generated .nuspec file, but the dll for the cl2 is not included in the lib folder of the .nupkg. So, whenever I consume this nupkg in other solution, I am getting error " No packages exist with this id in source(s)" for the cl2.

*Dependencies* are meant for **packages**. So when NuGet restores the package it searches for other packages that this package depends on, here `cl2`, but there is none, hence the error. When packing a project, referenced projects are **not** included in the package. That is an open [issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891) and there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979310/including-referenced-project-dlls-in-nuget-package-net-core-rc3-csproj-file) that you can try.

The most reliable, but inconvenient solutions are to avoid the issue at all.

- Only use a single project, everything will be included in the package
- Pack each project on its own and use the generated package instead of the referenced project

Comment: Thanks for answering it, let me try this workarounds.