# Modify dotnet pack auto generated nuspec

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I am using the csproj property `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` to generate a NuGet package from my netstandard2.0 C# project.

I would like to make 2 modifications to the generated package

1. Change the id to rename the package
2. Add an additional .dll to the .nupkg

The only way I could figure out to accomplish that was to add a custom .nuspec file to my project, and add `<NuspecFile>` to the .csproj.

This works fine, but I'm missing some features from the auto-generated NuGet package, like repository binding to my git commit. It also feels less resilient to change.

Is there any way I can modify the SDK build process to get the auto-generated NuGet package, but with my 2 changes?

Comment: [Here's an explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-an-icon-image-file) of how to add a file to your package through msbuild

Comment: And you can add your own target to alter your nuspec file `<Target Name="AlterNuspec" BeforeTargets="GenerateNuspec">` or smth like that

Comment: The .dll I want to add is generated by a `ProjectReference`'d project. I tried adding `IncludeAssets` after I removed my .nuspec, but the .dll isn't added to the generated .nupkg. You've given me some good stuff to try, though, so thanks very much.

Comment: And, if this doesn't work, I can always lean on adding a custom target to xslt the auto generated .nuspec file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Pieterjan, I found the right answer.

[Including referenced project DLLs in nuget package [.Net Core RC3 *.csproj file]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979310/including-referenced-project-dlls-in-nuget-package-net-core-rc3-csproj-file)

pointed me to

https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/3891#issuecomment-377319939

so I was able to

1. Rename the PackageId property in a `<Target Name="MyProj_RenamePackageId" BeforeTargets="GenerateNuspec"`
2. Follow the steps of issue 3891 above to add the referenced project .dll to the produced .nupkg

Comment: @Pieterjan, I will give you the answer checkmark, if you want. Thanks again for the help